# PHP strpos() and str_replace()

Tags: php, str-replace, strpos

I got a problem with my small php script.

My code should function as a follow-/unfollow-system like in forum softwares (for example XenForo).

So what my script does is that it searches for a user in a string and if the name is found it removes the name of the user in the string. But my problem is that the script can not search for the name and comma for some reason because I try to remove the comma from the string aswell.

*Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)*

**Example**:

Peter is following Franz and George but he want's to unfollow George

**Script**:

```
<?php

$user1 = "Peter";
$following1 = "Franz, George";

$user2 = "Franz";
$following2 = "Peter, George";

$user3 = "George";
$following3 = "Peter, Franz";


//
//
//

if (strpos($following1, $user3) == true) {
    echo "Can remove follow.";

    if (strpos($following1, ", $user3")) {
        $user3 = ", $user3";
        $fNew = str_replace($user3, "", $following1);
        echo "$fNew<br>";
    } else if (strpos($following1, "$user3, ")) {
        $use3 = "$user3, ";
        $fNew = str_replace("$user3", "", $following1);
        echo "$fNew<br>";
    }
} else if ($following1 == $user3) {
    echo "Can remove follow.";
    $fNew = str_replace($user3, "", $following1);
    echo "$fNew<br>";
} else {
    echo "Can't remove follow";
}

?>
```

Comment: why not explode the string with a comma delimited and then unset where value == 'string'?

Comment: Your problem is that you are storing this data as a comma-separated string in the first place. You should be using arrays instead, resp. properly _normalize_ this when it comes to the point where you want to handle data storage using a database.

Comment: you should use !== false, not == true as strpos returns the position of the found string

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You're right, that would've been so simple! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TheDusty01 no worries :) take not of Paul's comment though - if strpos finds an item, it doesn't return a bool val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look a this:

```
<?php

$follow = "Peter, Franz, Spongebob";
$guyToUnfollow = 'Franz';

$people = explode(',', $follow);
var_dump($people);
foreach ($people as $key => $person) {
    $person = trim($person);
    if ($person == $guyToUnfollow) {
        unset($people[$key]);
    }
}

$follow = implode(',',$people);

var_dump($follow);
```

Firstly, we convert the CSV to an array, then loop through it. We use trim to remove whitespace, and unset any value in the array that matches the guy you want to unfollow. Finally, we recreate the csv using implode.

See it working here https://3v4l.org/QEnHj

Comment: Makes sense as I am looking at it thank you so much for your help!

Comment: why not use in_array? you don't need to use foreach for this

Comment: Ok, so it's in the array Paul. How would you unset it?

Answer (score 0):

strpos returns the position of the string, so you need to check if its not false in stead of checking if its true.
So you should use:

```
strpos($following1, $user3) !== false
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, users can hack this system by simply choosing nicknames which are a substring of a different users nickname.

Comment: I'm just answering the question, I agree its always better to use a database nickname system

Comment: I am using a database system this was just a dirty 'try it out' script. Thank you though!